# Optional parameter in url routing asp.net 4.0 (not in MVC)?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

Is it possible to have optional parameter in Url routing while using asp.net 4.0?

I mean i just pass value for one parameter and skip value for another parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us more details ?!

Answer (score 1):

I can not give you an answer (I am still searching as well) but maybe a workaround.
As far as I understand your question you want to be able to do the following:

> a) my-pets.com/dog/brown/long/good-temper
>
> b) my-pets.com/dog///mean-barker
>
> c) my-pets.com/dog/black/

The user would be able to leave out a parameter (in the example b), the color of the dog and the kind of fur (short or long)

My workaround does the following:

```
string furType = Page.RouteData.Values["furType"] == null ? "-" :     Page.RouteData.Values["furType"].ToString();
```

This allows the following route

> http://my-pets.com/dog/-/-/mean-barker

In my code I use it to filter values from the database

```
var pet = new Pet();
pet.getPets(pet.filter(petType="dog", petTemper="mean-barker");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
       "ProductsBrowse",
        "browse/{BrowseBy}/{Category}",
        "~/Pages/Products/Browse.aspx",
        false,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "Category", string.Empty } }
    );
```

[asp.net webforms routing: optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781092/asp-net-webforms-routing-optional-parameters)

Comment: i don't think it is possible in web form. how about leaving the BrowseBy parameter as emtpy? then will it be like 'browse//category' ?