# ASP.NET Routing optional first parameter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, routes

I am new ASP.NET Routing and have a question.

On the site I am developing, visitors sign up and create an account (with a display name), such as JohnDoe and the site personalises itself, with information pertaining to the display name.

For example (in order of the routing table, I currently have):

```
http://www.domain.com/          -   Generic index page
http://www.domain.com/Page1     -   Generic page1
http://www.domain.com/Page2     -   Generic page2
http://www.domain.com/JohnDoe       -   Personalised index page
http://www.domain.com/JohnDoe/Page1 -   Personalised page1
http://www.domain.com/JohnDoe/Page2 -   Personalised page2
```

The above is working fine (I simply have a rule for every eventuality).

My problem is that, I now need to create asp:HyperLink controls on the pages of the site. Currently, I am using this:

```
NavigateUrl="<%$ RouteUrl:RouteName=ROUTENAME %>"
```

....in the tag of the HyperLink control

How can I, given the following addresses....

```
http://www.domain.com/Example       -   Generic example page
http://www.domain.com/JohnDoe/Example   -   Personalised example page
```

....match ROUTENAME, where the first parameter can be optional?

I could obviously create two routes, as follows....

```
Routes.MapPageRoute("Example_No_Displayname", "Example", "~/Example.aspx")
Routes.MapPageRoute("Example_With_Displayname", "{Code}/Example", "~/Example.aspx")
```

....but that means that the route names need to be different and I need to bind the Hyperlink control to match both of them.

I hope I have made myself clear and I appreciate any assistance the community may be able to give.

Answer (score 0):

It would be somewhat atypical to put the username itself in the URL.  The actual user identity/name would typically be extracted from some established security context/token, such as a cookie, so you could use the same URLs for both the anonymous pages and the personalized pages.  Is there a specific reason you want to have the username in the URL?

Comment: The username is simply for example purposes for this question. The username would be a display name, on the site I am writing. Nothing to do with security. I will edit the question so that there is no further confusion.

Comment: Probably better for me to say that people will give the personalised site address out, to their friends. Think facebook.com/JohnDoe :) Nothing to do with security or being logged in to my site.

Comment: OK, makes sense.  Is there any reason you can't just use one route with an optional parameter?  Essentially this would be the second route you listed above with the {Code} parameter, except with a default specified for the Code.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7133692/480588.

Comment: I did try that but, if you look at all the examples where an optional parameter is used, not one specifies the method when the first part after the domain name is optional. For instance: http://www.domain.com/Example       -   Generic example page
http://www.domain.com/JohnDoe/Example   -   Personalised example page

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to match directly on the route name if you use the [GetRouteUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getrouteurl.aspx) method.  That way you can still use the two routes you need to make this work.  See the full sample [here](http://petterisbetter.com/michael/media/stackoverflow/WebApplication1.zip).

Comment: Thanks very much for the sample code, which worked flawlessly. The only problem I have, even with the sample you gave, is that on my site, the action parameter doesn't match the physical name of the file. Imagine that I need the the action parameter to be "my_profile" and the page it has to go to is "MyProfile.aspx". I am trying to adapt your sample, using the GetRouteUrl method (for being able to handle those HyperLink controls) to take into account "my_profile/{code}" and "/my_profile" when the actualy physical name of the file is MyProfile.aspx.

Comment: I updated the sample to include a quick and dirty way of mapping the action name to a different page name.

Comment: Sorry about getting back to you. Thank you for your assistance.