# problems by using routing asp.net

Tags: asp.net, routes

> Hi to all i'm beginner in ASP.net ,i'd try using routing to introduce
>   some solutions by following code in global.asax:

```
 protected void RoutingHandler(string routeName, string repUrl, string Url)
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(routeName,repUrl,Url);
        }
   protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {         
            RoutingHandler("SolutionsRoute", "Solutions/{name}", "~/Pages/Solutions.aspx");
            RoutingHandler("SolutionsPageRoute", "Solutions", "~/Pages/Solutions.aspx");
        }
```

> and it work good ,I'd use  to link the page
>   in my menu but when i'm in the url if click again on the other link
>   the url cheng like this /**Solutions**/**Solutions**/VDI
>   how can I solve this problems

Comment: The problem is not in your configuration, it's in the URL generation itself. Simply restructure your links, instead of having href="solutions/test" in the solution pages, use href="/solutions/test". The difference is starting with / which indicates root, and from there your routing will hit properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems was at the href's link that was like this solutions/security i'd placed  a forwad slash behind of the url like this /solutions/security

Answer (score 0):

your problem is likely due to having two routing declarations for the same page. While this is valid it is not a recommended method. You should change your deceleration to instead specify a default null value  like this

```
protected void RoutingHandlerWDefault(string routeName, string repUrl, 
         string Url, bool chkURL, string varOne)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute(routeName,repUrl,Url, chkURL, 
                chkUrl, new RouteValueDictionary { { varOne, string.Empty } });
    }
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        RoutingHandlerWDefault("SolutionsRoute", "Solutions/{name}", "~/Pages/Solutions.aspx", 
                false, "name");
    }
```

SO Reference: [asp.net webforms routing: optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781092/asp-net-webforms-routing-optional-parameters)

Also note that you may want to change how you link to your urls. you can find references on how to link to routed urls in these links.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668176.aspx

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111718/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012710-1.aspx